# execute a method after dll method fired up

Tags: c#, dll, reflection

i want make a dll file include some methods like :

```
add()
edit()
list()
get()
delete()
...
```

so i want found out when a method fired ( something like logging )
i want every time an event in my dll fired, call a method in project ( that include dll as reference )

i can't use like this :

```
mydllclass.add();
mymethod();
```

i want a way that make it happen after all method calls ( from anywhere ) mymethod be call.

for example if edit() called inside add() method body, i want to found out that.

So :

```
bProject    
 + default.aspx
 + bin > mydll.dll ===> [ add() edit() ... ]
 + myclass > mymethod() ===> target !
```

how should be my classes and my methods in dll ? and how can solve it ?

( or better suggestion )

thank you

Comment: Fire a event every time one of the methods is calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare an `event` that fires every time your method was called. (You can always use **AOP** for better structure.)

```
class TestClass
{
    public event Action<string> MethodCall;

    public void Add()
    {
        MethodCall("Add Called");

        Edit();
    }

    public void Edit()
    {
        MethodCall("Edit Called");
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var c = new TestClass();
        c.MethodCall += Console.WriteLine;

        c.Add();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Would output:

```
Add Called
Edit Called
```

Comment: that was great help.
i didn't work with events like that before, so i need some search and try.

thanks for AOP too ;)

Comment: @Bojbaj Glad to help.